# Plotting Gradient for Line chart using ggplot_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Below is the a small dataset which i have tried to reproduce it to my best understanding.As in the attached plot you can observe that i am able to gradient in geom_point() but the same visuals i am trying for geom_line.`Note : we are always been provided with data of`Temp`and`var`.The`cat` variable is not given in data set.

```
df=data.frame(seq=(1:30),Temp =rnorm(30,mean = 34 ,sd=18))
f=summary(df$Temp)
df$cat <- cut(df$Temp,
                   breaks=c(f[1], f[3] ,f[4] ,f[6]),
                   labels=c("low","medium","high"))
f=ggplot(df , aes(x=seq ,y= Temp,colour=cat))+ geom_line()
f
```

**Output of Above Code**
[image]

**Required Output**
[image]

Gradient should as per `High` , `Medium` & `Low` using geom_line() function in ggplot2.

Answer (score 3):

You want to group the lines by `cat`, but colour them by `Temp`. For getting a nice gradient, I like the colour scales in the `viridis` package, but you can play around with `scale_colour_gradient` instead:

```
library(viridis)
ggplot(df , aes(x=seq ,y= Temp,colour=Temp, group = cat)) + 
    geom_line(size = 1.2) +
    scale_colour_viridis(option = "A")
```

Output:

[image]

To have a legend for the lines, you can represent `cat` with something like
shape:

```
ggplot(df , aes(x=seq ,y= Temp,colour=Temp, group = cat, shape = cat)) + 
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    geom_line(size = 1.2) +
    scale_colour_viridis(option = "A")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
a <- data.frame(seq=(1:30),Temp =rnorm(30,mean = 34 ,sd=18))

ggplot(a, aes(x = seq, y = Temp, color = Temp )) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.5)  +
  geom_smooth(aes(color=..y..), size=1.5, method = "loess", se=FALSE) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow" , high = "red", 
                         midpoint=median(a$Temp))
```

Comment: absolute somewhat closer But i need it to be enclosed with `plotly` for interactive visuals i tried saving ggplot object in `i` variable and further i executed a command `ggplotly(i)' there is't any visuals coming over their. And i am getting an error getting is ``geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess'`

Comment: Not an error, just a warning, isn't it? Anyways, working on it, sir

Comment: i appreciate your code , it would be very helpful if we can have plotly feature with it, what i usually do is once the ggplot object is made i enclose the `ggplot plot object ` in   `ggplotly()` to make it interactive plot similar to `plotly feature of interaction`

Comment: Have you tried the plot with `ggplotly()`. I'm currently trying to fix this `We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with ggplotly()
Install it with: devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`

Comment: ,Hey look i am same code of your in plotly object here is the code .`a <- data.frame(seq=(1:30),Temp =rnorm(30,mean = 34 ,sd=18))

i=ggplot(a, aes(x = seq, y = Temp, color = Temp )) + 
  geom_line()  +
  #geom_smooth(aes(color=..y..), size=1.5, se=FALSE) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "blue" , high = "red", 
                         midpoint=median(a$Temp))
ggplotly(i)` here the line is not visible but when we move the cursor over the chart it shows `Temp` Value ..this would really interactive plot . Thank you for the support .

Comment: Yeah, the same issue. Hence I was trying to reinstall `ggplot2` from github. But my machine wont do that and giving me `dependency tibble is not available for package ggplot2` ...